# How to reject nonexisting enum strings in SOAP webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, enums, jaxb

I have a `SOAP` webservice (jaxws) whose request object has an `enum`. I want to make this enum required and reject/fail the request if an enum has been inserted that is unknown to the server.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RequestObjekt {
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false)
    private TypeMyEnum value;
}
```

But I can pass values that are not defined in `TypeMyEnum`. Why? How can I tell the webservice to reject any request that has invalid enum strings?

Comment: Until I can have a definitive answer, here is an entry that cand give you an idea: http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/jax-ws-schemavalidation-custom-handler.html